# adding content above recent posts in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I am trying to insert meta slider to display above my posts in wordpress.

I correctly inserted the code in the theme index.php file above the loop. it works correctly, but it also displays on top of the side bar as well, and i would like it just above the posts.

is there any advice on how i can do this? where in the loop would i need to insert it?

here is what i have

```
<?php
/**
 * The main template file
 *
 * @package SimpleMag
 * @since   SimpleMag 1.0
**/
get_header();
global $ti_option;
?>

<?php $archive_sidebar = get_field( 'page_sidebar', get_option('page_for_posts') ); ?>

    <section id="content" role="main" class="clearfix animated">


<?php 
    echo do_shortcode("[metaslider id=437]"); 
?>

        <?php if ( $ti_option['posts_page_title'] == 'full_width_title' ) : ?>
        <header class="entry-header page-header">
            <div class="wrapper title-with-sep page-title">
                <h1 class="entry-title">
                    <?php
                    $posts_page_id = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );
                    echo get_the_title( $posts_page_id );
                    ?>
                </h1>
            </div>
        </header>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="wrapper">
        <?php
        // Enable/Disable sidebar based on the field selection
        if ( ! $archive_sidebar || $archive_sidebar == 'page_sidebar_on' ):
        ?>
            <div class="grids">
                <div class="grid-8 column-1">
        <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if ( $ti_option['posts_page_title'] == 'above_content_title' ) : ?>
                <header class="entry-header page-header">
                    <div class="title-with-sep page-title">
                        <h1 class="entry-title">
                            <?php
                            $posts_page_id = get_option( 'page_for_posts' ); 
                            echo get_the_title( $posts_page_id ); 
                            ?>
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                </header>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <div class="grids <?php echo $ti_option['posts_page_layout']; ?> entries">
                    <?php 
                    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts()) : the_post();
                        get_template_part( 'content', 'post' );
                    endwhile;
                    ?>
                </div>

                <?php ti_pagination(); ?>

                <?php else : ?>

                <p class="message">
                    <?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts were found', 'themetext' ); ?>
                </p>

                <?php endif;?>

                <?php
                // Enable/Disable sidebar based on the field selection
                if ( ! $archive_sidebar || $archive_sidebar == 'page_sidebar_on' ):
                ?>
                </div><!-- .grid-8 -->

                <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

            </div><!-- .grids -->
            <?php endif; ?>

        </div><!-- .wrapper -->
    </section><!-- #content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: That's hard to answer with just this code snippet. Does your theme have a home.php or front-page.php? And is this the whole content of index.php?

Comment: it does not have a home.php or front-page.php. i just updated my post with the full contents of index.php

Comment: I would try placing it after <div class="grid-8 column-1">

Comment: works like a charm, thank you!

Comment: No problem. Added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the sidebar is deactivated, your placement is fine. When the sidebar is active you should place it just below `<div class="grid-8 column-1">`. That's the beginning of the main area of your page, next to the sidebar. (I'm guessing the div is using something similar to bootstrap, taking up 8 of 12 available grids).

To prevent future updates of your theme to overwrite your customizations, if this is in fact a supported theme, you should also consider creating a child theme. It's real easy and is explained here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes